# Android Change main Fragment from child

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, drawer

I'm having some troubles with my Fragments management.. 
It's quite new for me and I'm pretty sure you'll find an easy way to solve my problem.

So I have a NavigationDrawer in a FragmentActivity and from this, I can navigate between two fragments.
One of those two fragments has children in a ViewPager.
I'd like to change the Parent Fragment from a ChildFragment which is in the ViewPager..

With my friend Paint, I drew my problem 

http://goo.gl/OGdf1c
So as you can see, I'd like to load FragmentA from Fragment2B

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform a normal `FragmentTransaction` and be sure to use the `FragmentManager` of the `Activity`!

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(...);
transaction.commit();
```

If your `Activity` is a `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity` you have to remember to use the support `FragmentManager`, aside from that everything stays the same:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(...);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is correct, and helped me to discover that my problem was hidden somewhere else !_____________________________________________________________________________

Anyway, I managed to load the FragmentA with a different method:
In FragmentActivity, I created a method `public void selectItem(final int position)` which loads the fragment requested in parameter. The only thing I do in my Fragment2b is to call `((MyFragmentActivity) getActivity()).selectItem(0);`_______________________________________________________ 
Thank you !